# Unable to check RadioButton inside DataList footer Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have kept two radio button inside a datalist footer template but I am not at all able to select it. Below is my footer template:

```
<FooterTemplate>
        <tr>
         <td align="right" colspan="7"><br />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" colspan="7">
        <div style="background-color:#FCEE21; height:47px ;">
        <div style=" position:relative; top:15px; left:20px;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAgree" Checked="true" Text="I agree on all terms & conditions" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style=" position:relative; top:-1px; left:410px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Total: (INR)"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style=" position:relative; top:-22px; left:550px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lbltotal" runat="server" Text="000000" Font-Size="14pt"></asp:Label>
        </div>
                       </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="7">
        <div style="background-image: url(images/footerBg.png); height:47px ;">
        <div style=" position:relative; top:10px; left:-172px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Select an option: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" Text="Colect" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="rboption"/>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" Text="Deliver" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="rboption"/>
        </div>
        <div style=" position:relative; top:-18px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" BackColor="#F8CD20" CssClass="anchor"
                BorderColor="#F8CD20" BorderStyle="None" OnClick=" Submit_Clicked" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="14pt" 
                Height="38px" Width="105px" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </FooterTemplate>
```

I have not done any databinding also. Please help me out, if I missed out something.

Comment: Do you mean using the code behind or via the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is about your css styling. If you remove inline css styles from your divs you can click them.

Those divs are displaying on top of each other without proper styles and radiobuttons stay under another div, prevents you clicking on them.

Or if you want to keep the styles and still click them you can use "z-index" attribute with adding `z-index:1;`, so you bring the div with radiobuttons, above the other div, making them clickable.

```
....
<div style=" position:relative; top:10px; left:-172px; z-index:1;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Select an option: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" Text="Colect" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="rboption"/>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" Text="Deliver" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="rboption"/>
</div>
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggling to get this.